# What does the hash in ${parameter/#pattern/string} do?

Tags: bash, string

I saw the following substitution in [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031015173932306):

```
${PWD/#$HOME/~}
```

How does it compare to this?

```
${PWD/$HOME/~}
```

Both seem to be the same. I don't know why the hash was included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`man bash`, explanation for `${parameter/pattern/string}`:

> If pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with %, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.

```
> var=abcd
> echo "${var/bc/_}"
a_d
> echo "${var/#bc/_}"
abcd
```

Answer (score 3):

Speaking about pattern matching and substitution in short for the ${parameter/pattern/string} format with some examples:

> If the pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.

```
> test=test
> echo ${test//t/-} 
> -es-
```

> If pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.

```
> test=test
> echo ${test/#t/-}
> -est
```

> If pattern begins with  %, it  must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.

```
> test=test
> echo ${test/%t/-}
> tes-
```

An example with using asterix `*`:

```
> test=test
> echo ${test/#*es/-}
> -t
```

**Reference:** `man bash`: `${parameter/pattern/string}`